# Regarding in-place merge in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort, space-complexity

I came across the following question.

Given an array of *n* elements and an integer *k* where *k* < *n*. Elements {*a*<sub>0</sub>...*a*<sub>*k*</sub>} and
{*a*<sub>*k*+1</sub>...*a*<sub>*n*</sub>} are already sorted. Give an algorithm to sort in O(*n*) time and O(1) space.

It does not seem to me like it can be done in O(*n*) time and O(1) space. The problem really seems to be asking how to do the merge step of mergesort but in-place. If it was possible, wouldn't mergesort be implemented that way? I am unable to convince myself though and need some opinion.

Comment: Does the question specifically state merge-sort? I know it is possible to merge sort in-place, but not in O(n) time (at least I've never heard of it.)

Comment: No, it does not. I am making the analogy to the merge step. It does look similar.

Comment: If you have posted the exact wording of the question, then it does not appear to have anything to do with mergesort. There are sorting algorithms that are O(1) space and O(n) in-place for a pre-sorted array (i.e. insertion sort). Mergesort is not one of them, and it is well-known that it is not one of them, so...

Comment: So how would you solve this problem then in O(n) time? What's the idea? May be you did not get the question here is an example... 
{1,3,5,8} and {2,4,6,9} .. What you are alluding to is a completely presorted array which is not the case for my question. It does not make sense to sort an already sorted array anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to merge two sorted integer array in place using O(n) time and O(1) space cost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126219/how-to-merge-two-sorted-integer-array-in-place-using-on-time-and-o1-space-cos)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.45.5606&rep=rep1&type=ps) seems to indicate that it is possible to do in O(lg^2 n) space.  I cannot see how to prove that it is impossible to merge in constant space, but I cannot see how to do it either.

Edit:
Chasing references, Knuth Vol 3 - Exercise 5.5.3 says "A considerably more complicated algorithm of L. Trabb-Pardo provides the best possible answer to this problem: It is possible to do stable merging in O(n) time and stable sorting in O(n lg n) time, using only O(lg n) bits of auxiliary memory for a fixed number of index variables.

More [references](http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/reprint/35/6/643.pdf) that I have not read.  Thanks for an interesting problem.

Further edit:
This article claims that the article by Huang and Langston have an algorithm that merges two lists of size m and n in time O(m + n), so the answer to your question would seem to be yes.  Unfortunately I do not have access to the article, so I must trust the second hand information.  I'm not sure how to reconcile this with Knuth's pronouncement that the Trabb-Pardo algorithm is optimal.  If my life depended on it, I'd go with Knuth.

I now see that this had been asked as and earlier Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126219/how-to-merge-two-sorted-integer-array-in-place-using-on-time-and-o1-space-cos) a [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm) of times.  I don't have the heart to flag it as a duplicate.

Huang B.-C. and Langston M. A., Practical in-place merging, Comm. ACM 31 (1988) 348-352

Comment: You are right. I am able to read the paper since I am the University. It seems like it is possible although the technique is quite sophisticated. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: You can find the paper at CiteSeerX. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.8523

Comment: @Daniel Thanks.  My googling skills need improvement.

Answer (score 2):

There are several algorithms for doing this, none of which are very easy to intuit.  The key idea is to use a part of the arrays to merge as a buffer, then doing a standard merge using this buffer for auxiliary space.  If you can then reposition the elements so that the buffer elements are in the right place, you're golden.

I have written up [an implementation](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=inplace-merge) of one of these algorithms on my personal site if you're interested in looking at it.  It's based on the paper "Practical In-Place Merging" by Huang and Langston.  You probably will want to look over that paper for some insight.

I've also heard that there are good adaptive algorithms for this, which use some fixed-size buffer of your choosing (which could be O(1) if you wanted), but then scale elegantly with the buffer size.  I don't know any of these off the top of my head, but I'm sure a quick search for "adaptive merge" might turn something up.

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't possible, although my job would be much easier if it was :).

You have a O(log n) factor which you can't avoid.  You can choose to take it as time or space, but the only way to avoid it is to not sort. With O(log n) space you can build a list of continuations that keep track of where you stashed the elements that didn't quite fit. With recursion this can be made to fit in O(1) heap, but that's only by using O(log n) stack frames instead.

Here is the progress of merge-sorting odds and evens from 1-9. Notice how you require log-space accounting to track the order inversions caused by the twin constraints of constant space and linear swaps.

```
.     -
135792468
 .   -
135792468
  :  .-
125793468
   : .-
123795468
    #.:-
123495768
     :.-
123459768
      .:-
123456798
       .-
123456789

123456789
```

There are some delicate boundary conditions, slightly harder than binary search to get right, and even in this (possible) form, and therefore a bad homework problem; but a really good mental exercise.

**Update**
Apparently I am mistaken and there is an algorithm that provides O(n) time and O(1) space. I have downloaded the papers to enlighten myself, and withdraw this answer as incorrect.

Comment: It is possible for a linked list. The O(log n) comes from somewhere else.

Comment: I can see how to do it with lg n extra space.  I cannot see how to prove that you cannot do better, i.e. that O(lg n) extra space is necessary to keep things linear.

Comment: @Joshua. It's not really fair to say it is possible with a linked list, because the list has O(n) extra pieces of information that make it easier -- the pointers from element to element.  If you could afford O(n) extra space, you could do just as well with an array.  You allocate a new result array, and just walk your two original arrays, copying the items out in order.

Comment: @deinst I didn't find it easy, but I did eventually prove to my satisfaction that lg n is the lower bound. That was years ago and unfortunately I no longer have it available. It is however reasonably straight forward to prove that whatever the lower-bound is it is higher than O(1), which is good enough for our purposes here.