# How to merge two sorted portions of same array in O(n) time and O(1) space

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to sort in-place using the merge sort algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm)
>   [Regarding in-place merge in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285756/regarding-in-place-merge-in-an-array)

Given an `array` of size `N`, which is divided into two sets of sorted integers(`0 to P` and `P+1 to N-1`). How would you sort this array using constant extra space (`O(1)`) and in `O(n)` time. For e.g

A = {1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8}, here N = 8, P = 3 and 
elements from 0 to 3 are sorted and elements from 4 to 7 are sorted.

Desired O/P: A = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

Comment: "how to merge two sorted integer array in place using O(n) time and O(1) space cost" : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126219/how-to-merge-two-sorted-integer-array-in-place-using-on-time-and-o1-space-cos

Comment: Would this be homework, perchance?

Comment: Who on earth would ask this on a job interview?!?

Comment: @Daniel Brückner Are you surprised at it because you think it is easy or hard?

Comment: Because it is hard. I guess the only people that would ask such questions are people not knowing the (correct) answer with the possible exception that you are looking for a job in the field of search algorithm research.

Answer (score 0):

Your input array doesn't need to be sorted.  You simply write out the numbers 0..N-1 (or 1..N your example is a bit confusing). I think you must have mis-stated your problem.

Comment: I'm guessing using the numbers 1-8 was just a toy example. He could have used any range of 8-unique numbers, like {1, 20, 21, 2, 3, 7, 50, 100}. This should yield the merged array {1, 2, 3, 7, 20, 21, 50, 100}.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can allocate a new array to hold the result.  So what you're doing is merging two sorted lists.  A simple two-way merge does that nicely.

Comment: Allocating a new array to hold the result is an O(n) extra space operation which is disallowed by his constraints.

Comment: `O(1)` space does not allow allocating a new array. All (known) solutions to this problem are freaking complex compared to the simplicity of the problem without the `O(1)` space constraint.

Comment: I was confused by his wording.  He said "O(1) extra space."  The "extra" led me to believe that he could allocate a new array.