# merging of two sorted halfs without extra memory!

Tags: c, sorting, merge

given an integer array of which first and second half are sorted. write a function to merge the two parts to create one single sorted array in place(do not use extra space).
one approach is
eg:
    // 1,3,6,8,-5,-2,3,8

```
int l = 0;
int u = size;
int mid = (l+u)/2;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
  for (j = mid; j < size; j++) {
    if (a[i] >= a[j]) {
      temp = a[j];
      for (i = mid-1; i >= 0; i--)
        a[i+1] = a[i];
      a[0] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

but i think there must be some O(n) algo for this..

Comment: I've formatted your code somewhat (using the `{}` button above the editor), but I think it could be neater - you could try editing your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Damien, formatted it better, and added missing variable types.

Comment: This would just be the last step of merge sort.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort thus O(n) because merge sort is O(n log n)

Comment: @Hogan There are just two chunks.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285756/regarding-in-place-merge-in-an-array

Comment: @cnicutar - yep two chunks.  Like I said the last step in merge sort.

Comment: @Hogan That's not where merge sort's `nlgn` is coming from. **Two arrays can be merged in linear time**, the constant space is the problem.

Comment: @Hogan - how does that help, given the O(1) space constraint?

Comment: @Hogan merge sort usually uses extra space, op isn't allowed to, and in-place merges can be harder to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to merge two sorted integer array in place using O(n) time and O(1) space cost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126219/how-to-merge-two-sorted-integer-array-in-place-using-on-time-and-o1-space-cos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at this again and here is your O(n-1) and memory(n+1):

```
/**
 * Created by deian on 2016-12-22.
 */
public class Merge {
    public static void swap(int[] a, int i1, int i2) {
        int t = a[i1];
        a[i1] = a[i2];
        a[i2] = t;
    }

    public static void merge(int[] a) {
        int i1 = 0;
        int i2 = a.length / 2;

        System.out.printf("    %s,      i(%d,%d)       \n",    Arrays.toString(a),    i1, i2   );
        for (int di = 0; di < a.length-1; di++) {
            int ni;
            int oi1=i1;
            int oi2=i2;
            // i1 and i2 - always point to the smallest known numbers
            if (a[i1] > a[i2]) {
                ni = i2;
                i2++;
                if (i2>=a.length) {
                    i2--;
                }
            } else {
                ni = i1;
                i1++;
                if (i1 >= i2) {
                    i1 = di;
                }
            }
            if (di == i1) {
                i1 = ni;
            }
            swap(a, di, ni);
            System.out.printf("#%d: %s, i(%d,%d)s(%d>%d)i(%d,%d) \n", di+1, Arrays.toString(a), oi1, oi2,ni, di, i1,i2);
        }
        System.out.printf("    %s\n", Arrays.toString(a));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        int[] a = new int[]{1, 3, 6, 8, -5, -2, 3, 8};
//        int[] a = new int[]{1, 3, 6, 8, -5, 2, 3, 8};
        int[] a = new int[]{1, 5, 6, 8, -5, 2, 3, 4};
        merge(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried running your code (after changing `ri == rs` to `ri = rs`) and it does not seem to work.

Comment: after the else if it should be `li++; ri = rs;` but this is not O(n) if you reset one of the index -- that goes to O(n log n)

Comment: @Hogan that simply can't be correct, since if you have `li++` on both branches of the `if` you will certainly finish in `O(n)`, just not always with the correct answer.

Comment: @sverre: You might be right, since it is clear this solution a second inner loop.  maybe something like if (a[li] =< a[ri]) li++; but after the ri = rs assignment.

Comment: @sverre and @hogan you are right. look at the latest - the idea is the same though - we need to keep the arrays sorted while we doing the swaps

Comment: @deian better, but what is the complexity (hint: it's not `O(n)`)?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed there are O(n) algorithms for merging in-place. They're usually quite complex though. For few ideas, please see the papers such as [Huang, Langston (PDF)](http://akira.ruc.dk/~keld/teaching/algoritmedesign_f04/Artikler/04/Huang88.pdf) or [Katajainen, Pasanen, Teuhola (PostScript)](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/jyrki/Paper/mergesort_NJC.ps). These are actually defined based on precise terms of what kind of extra memory is allowed, without cheating by using recursion stack and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by walking the array once, from 0 to it's last element.  You just need to think about what you need to compare or swap the "current" element against, and it becomes quite easy.

You'll have to keep a few extra variables around to track the current element, and the "other" element you need to compare it to.

Also, you might want to look into the major C code formatting styles.  There is no style that makes everyone 100% happy, but there are plenty of styles that make everyone unhappy.

---- Edited ----

Ok, this is much more like a "brain teaser" problem than a serious computer science problem.  The issue is that "extra memory" is very poorly defined, and so there's a tons of way you can achieve the outcome if you only remember that recursion is allowed in the programming language, and [that a recursive call requires extra stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (which nobody is going to consider memory allocation as it required by the programming language implementation).

Basically, such a question is meant to see if you look at a problem and see a recursive solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int index, int start1, int end1, int start2, int end2, int* array) {
  if (index >= end2) {
    return;
  }
  int lower;
  if (array[start1] <= array[start2]) {
    lower = array[start1];
    sort(index+1, start1+1, end1, start2, end2, array);
  } else {
    lower = array[start2];
    sort(index+1, start1, end1, start2+1, end2, array);
  }
  array[index]=lower;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int a[] = {1,3,6,8,-5,-2,3,8};
  sort(0, 0, 3, 4, 7, a);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", a[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Is it a cheat?  You decide.  However, the sort was done in-place, and the cached numbers were neatly tucked away in local space in the call the stack, where you cannot really allocate / de-allocate them.

Extra optimizations are possible, but they are improvements of the core idea: use recursion and the call stack to cache information.

Comment: @Edwin Buck are you sure you can do it in one pass with no auxiliary memory?

Comment: @sverre, yes you can.  You do need memory to hold the indexes, and it would be a little easier to have memory to act as a the holder for the element being swapped, but even if you don't have memory to act as a holder for the element being swapped, you can do it by the old XOR swap trick.

Comment: @sverre, the reason it is possible is because it's not a real sort, it's just a merge.  Imagine if it were two decks of already sorted cards, the answer would be to just pull the card with the lower value, one comparison and one pull per card is O(n).

Comment: @Edwin Buck I know it's not a sort, but I still don't get it, because after you swap the other part-array is no longer sorted.  In light of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126219/how-to-merge-two-sorted-integer-array-in-place-using-on-time-and-o1-space-cos I'm not the only one.  Could you post some code?

Comment: I can easily merge two decks of cards in-place, because they are linked lists and not arrays.  I just don't see how to generalize it to arrays.

Comment: @sverre, edited with a working code solution.  Like most questions of this sort, it's a trick question, which hinges on the exact definition of extra memory.  In this case, it requires no extra heap.

Comment: @Edwin: This is actually a serious computer science problem, see [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285756/) [instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126219) of this question. There's a precise definition of extra memory: it's all the memory you use other than to store original data. Here you're clearly using Θ(recursion depth) memory, and your recursion depth is Θ(array size) — in effect you are doing the merge with a copy of half the array, when the whole point of the question was do cope without this extra memory.

Comment: @Gilles: Indeed, this answer is not a solution to the problem. Hand-waving the memory usage of recursion away is an incorrect and extremely dangerous programming practice.

Comment: If you are doing your serious computer science research by asking stack overflow, bigger problems exist.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I've found, assuming you can't use any auxiliary memory, is to heapsort the array, which is `theta(n log n)`, somewhat faster than your current insertion sort scheme.

Answer (score 0):

any of following

```
void Merge(int array[N])
{
for(int i=N/2;i<N;i++){
    int j=i;
    while(array[j]<array[j-1]&& j>=1){
        int temp=array[j];
        array[j]=array[j-1];
        array[j-1]=temp;
        j--;
    }
}
}

void Merge2(int array[N])
{
for(int i=N/2;i<N;i++){
   int key=array[i];
   int j=i-1;
   while(array[j]>key&& j>=0){
           array[j+1]=array[j];
           j--;
   }
   array[j+1]=key;
}
}
```

Comment: bro with two nester loops that feels like bubble sort