# Is There an Alternative to insert and then sort

Tags: c++, sorting, insert, merge, stl-algorithm

If I have `vector<int> foo` and `vector<int> bar` both of which are sorted, and I want to merge them into `foo` such that the final result is sorted, does the standard provide me a method for doing this?

Obviously I can do:

```
foo.insert(foo.end(), bar.begin(), bar.end());
sort(foo.begin(), foo.end());
```

But I was hoping there was a one step algorithm to accomplish this.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge

Comment: @Mat: Does this make some sort of merge sort?

Comment: @Mat From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge : "The behavior is undefined if the destination range overlaps either of the input ranges (the input ranges may overlap each other)."

Comment: Merge into a temp, then swap.

Comment: @JonathanMee: So merge them into a new vector. Then move it to `foo` if you want the result there.

Comment: @Mat That is a worse solution than what I already have suggested in the question because it requires the creation of another temporary `vector`. Furthermore it does not satisfy the request for a "one step algorithm to accomplish this."

Comment: Worse in what sense? Time complexity - I don't think so. Memory overhead - yes, probably. swap is constant time and extremely quick. (If you're trying to save one line of code, ...)

Comment: @JonathanMee Is `std::list::merge` ([cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/merge)) a candidate for your one-liner?

Comment: Are you asking for in-place merge?

Comment: @Lingxi Yeah, one that I don't have to do two steps to acomplish

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi Wow, I didn't know about `list::merge`. That's exactly what I want but it looks like it's only available for `list`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be faster to use [`std::inplace_merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge) instead of `std::sort`. If there is additional memory available it has linear complexity otherwise it falls back to NlogN.

```
auto middle = foo.insert(foo.end(), bar.begin(), bar.end());
std::inplace_merge(foo.begin(), middle, foo.end());
```

Comment: @Lingxi: This algorithm attempts to allocate some temporary buffer memory to allow linear complexity, if it can't it uses a less efficient (NlogN) algorithm.

Comment: I upvoted, but let's be clear that under the hood, `std::inplace_merge()` does the exact same thing as TobiMcNamobi's code (assuming there's enough memory available), so if the OP is unhappy with that solution, he really ought to be equally unhappy with this one.

Comment: @j_random_hacker That's not true, TobiMcNamobi's solution doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217383/is-there-an-alternative-to-insert-and-then-sort/30238403#comment48578328_30217523

Comment: I have accepted this because it's the right answer, but a better evaluation of this answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30238403/2642059

Comment: @Blastfurnace I've been racking my brain trying to come up with a way to make sure we don't invalidate `foo.begin()` so we could compress this into one line, but I can't do it without a reserve: `inplace_merge(foo.begin(), foo.insert(foo.end(), bar.begin(), bar.end()), foo.end());`

Comment: @JonathanMee: To be honest, I would just write a function template that wraps these two steps. Since the order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified I think it's the only way to be sure the arguments to `std::inplace_merge` remain valid.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Yeah that was the comment at the end of my answer cause I couldn't find a workaround.

Comment: @JonathanMee: We know that `insert()` invalidates the `foo.end()` iterator regardless of the container's capacity. Combine that with the order of evaluation issue and it makes the idea of a one-liner very sketchy.

Comment: @JonathanMee: I read your comment claiming that TobiMcNamobi's code is broken, but you're mistaken.  I'm not sure why you think anything gets written to the end of `foo`.  The result gets written to `result`, and then that is copied to `foo` with `foo = result;`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yeah, I put a comment there too. I thought that he had used `back_inserter(foo)`. However even after reading it correctly I still believe that this answer is preferable. Because, it doesn't require me to create a temporary, and because `inplace_merge` takes advantage of the fact that the two ranges it's merging are already sorted.

Comment: @JonathanMee: Both `merge` and `inplace_merge` take advantage of (in fact, *require*) both ranges to be already sorted -- that's not a point of difference!

Comment: @j_random_hacker Chalk up another for you sir. I am doing poorly today. I trust you will allow me to cling to the fact that I don't have to make a temporary when I use `inplace_merge`?

Comment: @JonathanMee: No worries :) I think `inplace_merge` is indeed the more convenient choice here for that reason, and I've already harped on the fact that internally it will just do what TobiMcNamobi's code does, so cling away :)

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate on Mat's comment your code could look like this using `std::merge`:

```
std::vector<int> result;
std::merge(
    foo.begin(), foo.end(),
    bar.begin(), bar.end(),
    std::back_inserter(result));

foo = result; // if desired
```

Comment: That is a worse solution than what I already have suggested in the question because it requires the creation of another temporary `vector`. Furthermore it does not satisfy the request for a "one step algorithm to accomplish this."

Comment: It could be made more efficient by pre-allocating storage for `result`.

Comment: it has lower complexity, albeit not in one step. the last part can be a move, probably making it the fastest algorithm you could devise for this.

Comment: @JonathanMee: Linear-time in-place merges [exist, but they're crazy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126219/how-to-merge-two-sorted-integer-array-in-place-using-on-time-and-o1-space-co).  So you can object to the temporary vector, but in the end you'll wind up either writing it this way yourself, or calling an existing function (like `std::inplace_merge()`) that does it for you anyway.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi This doesn't work: `std::merge(foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), bar.end(), std::back_inserter(result));` It inserts the merge of both containers at the end of the first container.

Comment: @JonathanMee In my test program `std:merge` leaves `foo` and `bar` untouched and `result` is filled with the merged list just like the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) says.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi You are correct, my mistake, I thought your output said `back_inserter(foo)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this kind of merge, why not make one yourself?

```
template <class Vector>
void insert_sorted(Vector& where, Vector& what)
{
    typename Container::iterator src = what.begin();
    typename Container::iterator src_end = what.end();

    size_t index = 0;

    while(src != src_end)
    {
        if(*src < where[index])
        {
            where.insert(where.begin() + index, *src);
            ++src;
        }

        ++index;
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
vector<int> foo{ 0, 5, 7, 9, 11, 14 };
vector<int> bar{ 1, 2, 4, 8, 10, 12 };

insert_sorted(foo, bar);

for(vector<int>::iterator i = foo.begin(); i != foo.end(); ++i)
    cout << *i << " ";
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 12 14
```

Live sample: [link](http://ideone.com/ZRA6hA).

Comment: Writing your own is generally risky, when it comes to std algorithms. Although this particular problem is easy so I might consider it, but I wouldn't admit doing it. :)

Comment: Your algorithm is flawed. What if the last element, if any, of `where` is less than the first element of `what`?

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek Assertion when `foo` is smaller than `bar`. I concur with writing my own but this doesn't work.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek This will probably work better if you can descramble it from the comment: `for (Container::iterator toIterator = where.begin(), fromIterator = what.begin(); fromIterator != what.end(); ++fromIterator){while (toIterator != where.end() && *toIterator < *fromIterator)++toIterator;toIterator = where.insert(toIterator, *fromIterator);}`

Comment: That's a minimal solution, illustrating possible concept. Yes, it needs to be adjusted - note, however, that checking all possible situations (empty `where`, empty `what`, etc.) may not be necessary, if we can make some guarantees about content of parameters. Now, it's up to the OP to adjust this to his needs.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking through all the standard algorithms I can confirm that, **there is no alternative to `insert` and `sort`.** As I was searching the standard algorithms I did note that *all* the copying algorithms use input iterators and output iterators the only time an input-output iterators are used is when a single range is being operated on. (For example `sort` uses input-output iterators but any `copy` uses input iterators and an output iterator.)

I'd like to give an illustration of my point. So lets make an example of what an insertion merge algorithm with an input-output iterator would look like:

```
template <class BidirectionalIterator, class InputIterator>
void func(BidirectionalIterator first1, BidirectionalIterator last1, InputIterator first2, InputIterator last2){
    bool is1Empty = first1 == last1;
    bool is2Empty = first2 == last2;
    BidirectionalIterator end = next(last1, distance(first2, last2));

    if (!is1Empty){
        --last1;
    }

    if (!is2Empty){
        --last2;
    }

    while (!is1Empty || !is2Empty){
        --end;
        if (!is1Empty){
            if (!is2Empty && *last2 > *last1){
                *end = *last2;

                if (last2 == first2){
                    is2Empty = true;
                }else{
                    --last2;
                }
            }else{
                *end = *last1;

                if (last1 == first1){
                    is1Empty = true;
                }
                else{
                    --last1;
                }
            }
        }else{
            *end = *last2;

            if (last2 == first2){
                is2Empty = true;
            }
            else{
                --last2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Two things should be noted about this `func` algorithm:

1. It doesn't respect `last1` it is assumed that sufficient space is allocated beyond `last1` to also contain all the elements in the input range
2. `func`'s input-output range cannot be called with a `back_inserter` like any other output only range in a standard algorithm

Because of this even `func` cannot be a "one step algorithm". It must be called like this:

```
 foo.resize(foo.size() + bar.size());
 func(foo.begin(), next(foo.begin(), foo.size() - bar.size()), bar.begin(), bar.end());
```

Note that [Blastfurnace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30217827/2642059) takes advantage of the knowledge that it is merging two sorted ranges, and as such is of equivalent speed to `func`:

```
auto middle = foo.insert(foo.end(), bar.begin(), bar.end());
inplace_merge(foo.begin(), middle, foo.end());
```

The only actual "one step algorithm" is to roll this Blastfurnace's answer into a function that you could call by passing in the containers to be merged.